# TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given) python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
elif choice == "A":
    def add_task(count):
        with open ( 'user.txt' ) as fin:
            usernames = [ i.split ( ',' ) [ 0 ] for i in fin.readlines ( ) if len ( i ) > 3 ]
            task = input ( "Please enter the username of the person the task is assigned to.\n" )
        while task not in usernames:
            task = input ( "Username not registered. Please enter a valid username.\n" )
        else:
            task_title = input ( "Please enter the title of the task.\n" )
            task_description = input ( "Please enter the task description.\n" )
            task_due = input ( "Please input the due date of the task. (yyyy-mm-dd)\n" )
            date = datetime.date.today ( )
            task_completed = False
            if task_completed == False:
                task_completed = "No"
            else:
                task_completed = ("Yes")
            with open ( 'tasks.txt' , 'a+' ) as task1:
                count = count + 1
                task1.write ( "\n User assigned to task: " , str (
                    count ) + "\n" + task + "\nTask Title :" + "\n" + task_title + "\n" + "Task Description:\n" + task_description + "\n" + "Task Due Date:\n" + str (
                    task_due ) + "\n" + "Date Assigned:\n" + str (
                    date ) + "\n" + "Task Completed:\n" + task_completed + "\n" )
                file.close ( )
                print ( "The new assigned task has been saved" )
    count = 0
    add_task ( count )
```

Comment: Please expand this question to include: 1) an actual question.... and 2) the traceback error you are getting

Comment: File "C:/Users/Leechelle/PycharmProjects/Task 20/taskManager.py", line 67, in add_task
    task1.write("\n User assigned to task: " ,str(count) +"\n" + task + "\nTask Title :" + "\n" + task_title + "\n" + "Task Description:\n" + task_description + "\n" +"Task Due Date:\n" + str(task_due) + "\n" + "Date Assigned:\n" + str(date) + "\n" + "Task Completed:\n" + task_completed + "\n" )
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: Lee, can you edit the original question instead of answering things here in the comments?

Comment: In this line: `task1.write ( "\n User assigned to task: " , str (` replace `,` with `+`

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
task1.write ( "\n User assigned to task: " , str (
                count ) + "\n" + task + "\nTask Title :" + "\n" + task_title + "\n" + "Task Description:\n" + task_description + "\n" + "Task Due Date:\n" + str (
                task_due ) + "\n" + "Date Assigned:\n" + str (
                date ) + "\n" + "Task Completed:\n" + task_completed + "\n" )
```

With

```
task1.write ( "\n User assigned to task: " + str (
                count ) + "\n" + task + "\nTask Title :" + "\n" + task_title + "\n" + "Task Description:\n" + task_description + "\n" + "Task Due Date:\n" + str (
                task_due ) + "\n" + "Date Assigned:\n" + str (
                date ) + "\n" + "Task Completed:\n" + task_completed + "\n" )
```

You concatenate the first two strings with a comma, while all other strings are concatenated by a + sign.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `task1.write` line:

It should be:

```
task1.write ( "\n User assigned to task: " + str (count) + "\n" + task + "\nTask Title :" + "\n" + task_title + "\n" + "Task Description:\n" + task_description + "\n" + "Task Due Date:\n" + str (task_due) + "\n" + "Date Assigned:\n" + str (date ) + "\n" + "Task Completed:\n" + task_completed + "\n" )
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone that assisted , much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can change , to +   :

```py
task1.write(
    f"\nUser assigned to task: {count}" +
    f"\nTask:\n{task}" +
    f"Task Title:\n{task_title}" +
    f"Task Description:\n{task_description}" +
    f"Task Due Date:\n{task_due}" +
    f"Date Assigned:\n{date}" +
    f"Task Completed:\n{task_completed}\n"
)
```